# Obtaining label-node instead of city boundry polygon when using OSM Place Search in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins, nominatim

I am using [OSM Place Search Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/nominatim/) in QGIS for searching and importing places, cities, towns etc. from Openstreetmap database into my projects. Great Plugin by the way. But I have a big problem.

When searching for a city, e.g. München (Munich, Germany), the plugin always shows and imports the boundry as a polygon. Unfortunatelly that is not what I need. I would like to have the node imported, which works as the origin for the text label "München" and is marked as the city center. So I would like to have [this](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/1700534808) instead of [this](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/62428) imported.
As you might know the plugin uses Nominatim and in it's configuration dialog it provides the ability to filter the query by Nominatim specific API options.

[image]

I have read the docs and tried several configurations to make the plugin work as I need it, but I couldn't figure it out, as I am not an Nominatim pro.

Is there any way to tell the plugin to receive the node-label instead of of a (city) boundary from Nominatim?
Or are there other solutions to my problem? I am not limited to OSM Place Search, but I really need the  plugin's feature which includes several useful OSM information/keys in the imported layer's attribute table (E.g. capital = yes).
I know, there is the plugin [Geo Coding](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GeoCoding/), which behaves exactly how I want, but unfortunately it doesn't include any OSM keys into the attribute tables, except from the address.

Answer (score -1):

You could consider using the plugin QuickOSM and search for nodes that have place= city or place=town etc. This [link](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:place) gives all the values for the key place.  Here is a screenshot for settings and result for towns and cities in part of Germany:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer and taking the effort to create screenshots as well.
Yet I know this plugin and the suggested method. Unfortunately it doesn't fit my needs good enough. As not only me but also other people (with less qgis skills) will have to work with these maps I'd like to keep the workflow as easy to access as possible. Basically I am looking for a kind of Google Maps like marker setup: Searching a place > clicking it > recieving a marker as point layer (with osm key details in the attributes). I could ask my original question another way: Is there any way to tell Nominatim (by using